# Detect collisions for a lot of objects by coordinates in C++

Tags: c++, gdi, collision-detection

I am drawing and animating some objects using GDI. I need to detect a collision between these objects  and to change their direction of motion. My question is : is there any algorithm for the detection of object collision by coordinates in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a physics engine. Since you require only 2D, I suggest either [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) or [chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/). This is probably more easy than to implement it on your own.

Comment: i need just native C++ features to do that

Comment: What kind of "native C++ features" are you talking about? You'll always end up either using a existing library as suggested, or implementing your own, possibly along the lines of the suggestion by GETah.

Comment: @Bart i need to use just C++ standart libraries

Comment: `GDI` is not a native/standard library either. Just sayin... If you are using GDI you'd have to use pixel collision or something similar.

Comment: @Constantinius I know that GDI is not a standart library . What about collision , can you show an example ? (i cannot find )

Comment: There is no such thing as native/standard collision detection for C++.

Comment: @Bart: There is indeed native collision detect for C++. It simply involves writing a LOT of code. After all, someone had to write Box2D library in C++ in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 2D then I recommand you look into [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). 
(Heavily used in GIS applications) This [link](http://www.heroicvirtuecreations.com/QuadTree.html) has a C++ implementation of this special data structure

If you are in 3D then I recommand you look into [OcTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

Comment: Here's a neat quadtree animation I saw the other day: http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/09/09/quadtree-demonstration/